Must one remove one's chewing gum at shkia of Shabbat day?
Halacha requires not eating after shkia (sunset) on Shabbat day, in order to prevent one from missing havdala (SA OC 299:1 - exception being if one has washed before shkia, one may continue one's meal, MB al loc 2).
If one is in the middle of chewing gum at shkia, would one therefore have to remove it?

Thank you @Moishe for your comment, it is true that this question goes back to the question of making a bracha rishona and bracha achrona on gum (is it food?) which seems to be a machloket Achronim.
Here are some of the opinions:

Yabia Omer OC 7:33/Or L’Tzion 2:14:8/Igrot Moshe, OC 2:57/Beir Moshe 2:12/ Kinyan Torah 5:17- they say one requires a bracha on gum that is flavoured (it is food) therefore one would need to remove the gum at shekia.
Yaskil Avdi 8:7/Rav Chaim Tabasky/Rav Dov Lior in Devar Chevron 2:194/Rav Tuvia Goldstein/Rav Seraya Deblitzky quoted in Yitzchak Yeranen 37- they hold that gum does not need a bracha (even if flavoured), therefore one does not need to remove gum at shekia.
Rav Yisroel Belsky rules that hard gum requires a blessing while soft gum does not. The reason for the difference is that pieces of the shell of hard gum are inevitably swallowed when chewing it- so depending which type of gum it is, you would be able to decide based on the above.

You can find more sources of modern poskim in the above Teshuva in Yabia Omer.
Hope this helps!
Source: https://outorah.org/p/30577/#_ftn5

Is there no difference between flavored and non-flavored gum?

Do you have a source there compares this to the bracha question? Eating gum before davening is permitted by the MB 90:45 because it isn’t swallowed. Maybe eating before havdala because you might forget is similar to that, and it is permitted since it’s not swallowed. You did not present any proof to your premise

@mbloch, seems like most poskim (including: Halacha Berurah 10 page 520, Chazon Eliyahu OC 9, Ketter David page 90, Yalkut Yosef 204:18 footnote 18 etc) would hold that for non-flavored gum one would not say a bracha since there is no sweetness or benefit that one gets out of it (one would not say a bracha on merely just getting to chew on gum that could be healthy for his teeth)

@Chatzkel, that's a good point. I think we need to differentiate between the reason of eating before shacharit and eating before havdala (as you have implied). The Gemera in Brachot 10b says you can't eat because of arrogance, but as the Mishneh Berurah says there is no arrogance by chewing gum, but by havdala there the only reason we can't eat is because of forgetting to do havdala. Also see here: https://dinonline.org/2013/09/10/chewing-gum-on-yom-kippur/ that they make a comparison between making a bracha on gum and Yom Kippur which is similar to this case.

@AvishaiTebeka that is what I had understood as well and I'm glad you clarified in the answer. Thanks !

@AvishaiTebeka the question of the bracha and Yom Kippur are similar that it revolves around the issue of tasting food. Eating before davening isn’t so much an issue of taste, but rather the actual action of eating. Since one doesn’t swallow it, the action isn’t called eating in this regard. Eating before havdala may be an issue of action and not taste. This makes it similar to havdala not Yom Kippur

@Chatzkel is there any other conceivable scenario where one might have to remove food from one's mouth for the sake of not missing a mitzva? Establishing the principles to use here seems like the first step

Can one chew gum before hearing megillah?
